# pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmismatched inpu

Tags: python, pyspark

I have this simple statement, which is take 3 parameters into a sql statement, can someone explain my this error is generating in pyspark

```
>>> db_name = 'my_db'
>>> process_year = '2019'
>>> process_month = '10'
>>> df_rc_dp = spark.sql("""select count(*) as RC_COUNT, from {0}.test_table where sys_rec = 'remote' and year={1} and month={2}""".format(db_name, process_year, process_month))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in

File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 716, in sql
return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**
File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 73, in deco
raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
**pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmismatched input '.' expecting** (line 1, pos 44)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect count(*) as RC_COUNT, from my_db.test_table where sys_rec = 'remote' and year=2019 and month=10\n--------------------------------------------^^^\n"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

`data = {'db_name': 'my_db', 'process_year': 2020, 'process_month': 10} df_rc_dp = spark.sql("select count(*) as RC_COUNT from {db_name}.test_table where year={process_year} and month={process_month}".format(**data))`